# Sending binary data in an ajax post

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to send binary data as part of a complex type.  The model for my type is something like this:

```
class Message
{
  /* various properties that are ints/dates*/
  int type;
  datetime datedeleted;
  etc ...
  /*blob type which is actually a byte array*/
  byte[] messagecontent;

}
```

So I have two REST methods.  One converts and uploaded file to our proprietary format and then sends it back as  a complex type which I then store in form variables.

```
self.createMessage = function () {
        self.loading(true);
        var formdata = new FormData();
        jQuery.each($('#file')[0].files, function (i, file) {
            formdata.append('file-' + i, file);
        });
        dataModel.createMessage(formdata)
        .done(function (data) {
            self.messageValue(data.MessageValue);
```

So, if you inspect the page you will see something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="MessageValue" data-bind=" value: messageValue" value="iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAfQAAAHRCAYAAACct0sPA ... />
```

I then have another function that is triggered when the user clicks send.

```
self.sendMessage = function () {

        dataModel.sendMessage({
            MessageType: self.messageType(),
            ToUser: {
                UserName : self.selectedContactName()
            },
            MessageValue: window.atob(self.messageValue()),
```

This line:
**MessageValue: window.atob(self.messageValue())**,

I have tried it with and without the atob.  I have tried changing the content encoding.  I have tried it with the " data:image/png;base64," + messageValue().

None of those seem to work.  The web service throws a validation error saying that it cannot convert the given text to byte

I forgot to add the code for dataModel.sendMessage

```
self.sendMessage = function (data) {
        return $.ajax(messageSendUrl, {
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            headers: getSecurityHeaders()
        });
    };
```

Comment: When sending a FormData object via jQuery ajax you have to specify `contentType: false, processData: false` in your call.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this. Is it to save bandwidth? In which case all content could be gzipped by your webserver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually decided to go a different route.  In my Model I changed the type from a byte array to a string and just base64 encoded it, then i unencoded it on the second call.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript provides little support for reading binary data by default. You could look into serializing it. There is a few libraries out there that can do some form of binary data reading afaik.

See something like [this](http://jsfromhell.com/classes/binary-parser) or https://github.com/vjeux/jParser.